# Send input data to another action

Tags: php, yii2

So I have an action "Send" in my "DocumentsController". In the view I have a simple form:

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action'=>'/documents/sent']); //this is not *send* this is *sent*
?>
<?php
     echo $form->field($model, 'comment')->textarea(['rows' => '3'])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Comment'))
?>
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Send'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php
    ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

As you can see, I am trying to send the input data from **send** action to **sent** action. But when I press submit button the *print_r($_POST)* in sent action is EMPTY. Why? I want to get the values of the inputs from my **send** form in the **sent** action.

Comment: public function actionSent() {print_r($_POST) }

Comment: Please show us `sent()` code? it need to be `public function sent() { print_r( $this->input->post()); }`

Comment: update your question and show us the related   controller (DocumentsControllers )

Comment: [**`EDIT`**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49827799/edit) your question and add, `controller/action` code.

Comment: @HugeD Does `public function actionSent() {var_dump($_POST); exit; }` displays anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find it in:
`Yii::$app->request->post()` instead of `$_POST`.
For some reasons The `$_POST` variable is empty.